# Why do I keep getting an error with s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I'm just trying to make a basic HTML page. I barely have any code on the files at all, all the settings on my public, I used AWS Amplify to deploy from S3. Yet I'm still getting an error (see below)

```
<Error>
     <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
     <Message>Access Denied</Message>
     <RequestId>CJFYDW4WCHEKFZ9R</RequestId>
     <HostId>
         u69tPoAu3sxMa3pfONkSQuw7tU6J+CkOF/eytKQnT35Bm/1cKwg/fc9vCvgwRLta9bs2Yi66XRw=
      </HostId>
</Error>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Everything, the bucket, the files, etc. are public. I'm not understanding why I'm gettting this error.

Comment: What is the bucket policy? Have the bucket public settings been set to false?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/manual-deploys.html

> Note
>
> When you create the zip folder, make sure you zip the contents of your
> build output and not the top level folder. For example, if your build
> output generates a folder named “build” or “public”, first navigate
> into that folder, select all of the contents, and zip it from there.
> If you do not do this, you will see an “Access Denied” error because
> the site's root directory will not be initialized properly.

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>4442587FB7D0A2F9</RequestId>
  <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```